# "LNK1104: cannot open file mclmcrrtd.lib" Error in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qmake, matlab-compiler

I generated `*.dll` dynamic-link library file by compiling the application I developed in MATLAB using MRC (MATLAB Runtime Compiler). I'm using the MSVC compiler and qmake toolset in the Qt Creator environment to distribute and/or use the procedures in the application I developed in MATLAB in the Windows OS environment. But I'm having trouble adding the dynamic-link libraries (for example `mclmcrrt.lib`, `libmx.lib`, `libmex.lib`, `libmat.lib`, `libfixedpoint.lib`, etc.) shared by the MATLAB Runtime Compiler to my project. When I build the project in the Qt Creator environment, I get the following error:

```
* LNK1104: cannot open file 'mclmcrrtd.lib'

* U1077: "\VS\Tools\MSVC\{Version}\bin\HostX86\x64\link.EXE": return code '0x450'

* U1077: "\VS\Tools\MSVC\{Version}\bin\HostX86\x64\nmake.exe": return code '0x2'
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1. Definition of Error

I tested this bug by starting a similar project. When I compile the project in [Qt Creator](https://www.qt.io/product/development-tools) I got the following error:

> [LNK1104](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk1104): cannot open file 'mclmcrrtd.lib'

#### 2. Steps To Fix The Error

Follow the steps below to fix the problem:

1. I didn't add dependencies manually in **QT Creator**. I added a dynamic library by right-clicking on the project name and going to `Add Library > External Library`. I used the following settings in the **External Library** window in **QT Creator**, I added files and directories using these settings:

```
 * Linkage: Dynamic
 * Mac: Library

 * [✔] Library inside "debug" or "release" subfolder
 * [ ] Add "d" suffix for debug version
 * [ ] Remove "d" suffix for release version
```

2. I examined how the window opened in the second step transfers information about the dynamic library to the ***.pro** file. I selected the `mclmcrrt.lib` file in the `~/lib/win64/` directory and clicked the **Next** button in the **External Library** window on **Qt Creator**. I saw that the `mclmcrrt.lib` library was named differently in **Win32**, **Win64** and **Unix** systems when imported to **Qt Creator** in this way (like `lmclmcrrt`, `lmclmcrrtd`, `lmclmcrrt`).

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/'../../../../Program Files/MATLAB/R2018B/extern/lib/win64/microsoft/' -lmclmcrrt
else:win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/'../../../../Program Files/MATLAB/R2018B/extern/lib/win64/microsoft/' -lmclmcrrtd
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/'../../../../Program Files/MATLAB/R2018B/extern/lib/win64/microsoft/' -lmclmcrrt

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/'../../../../Program Files/MATLAB/R2018B/extern/lib/win64/microsoft'
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/'../../../../Program Files/MATLAB/R2018B/extern/lib/win64/microsoft'
```

3. This is how I learned how to properly import files and directories into my project file. I added all the requirements manually myself; I didn't use the interface to avoid file and directory confusion.

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/'../../../../Program Files/MATLAB/R2018B/extern/lib/win64/microsoft/' -lmclmcrrt
else:win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/'../../../../Program Files/MATLAB/R2018B/extern/lib/win64/microsoft/' -lmclmcrrtd
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/'../../../../Program Files/MATLAB/R2018B/extern/lib/win64/microsoft/' -lmclmcrrt

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/'../../../../Program Files/MATLAB/R2018B/extern/include'
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/'../../../../Program Files/MATLAB/R2018B/extern/include/win64'
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/'../../../../Program Files/MATLAB/R2018B/extern/lib/win64/microsoft'
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/'../../../../Program Files/MATLAB/R2018B/extern/lib/win64/microsoft'
```

4. When using the `Build > Rebuild All Projects` command in **Qt Creator** to compile the project, I got the error `LNK1104: Cannot open file 'mclmcrrtd.lib'` again. I found out that this is because the old [MATLAB Compiler Runtime (MCR)](https://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/matlab-runtime.html) is only suitable for *x86 architecture*. For this reason, I discovered that many sample *QT-Matlab Compiler Runtime* projects on the internet use the `win32` tag in the descriptions in ***.pro** files. However, I thought it would not be correct to use the `win32` tag because of the phrase `HostX64\x64` when called from the `C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\{Version}\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.exe` directory of the current [MSVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options). The final configuration in the ***.pro** file containing the relevant code block is as follows and successfully

```
LIBS += -L$$PWD/'../../../../Program Files/MATLAB/R2018B/extern/lib/win64/microsoft/' -lmclmcrrt
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/'../../../../Program Files/MATLAB/R2018B/extern/include'
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/'../../../../Program Files/MATLAB/R2018B/extern/include/win64'
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/'../../../../Program Files/MATLAB/R2018B/extern/lib/win64/microsoft'
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/'../../../../Program Files/MATLAB/R2018B/extern/lib/win64/microsoft'
```

#### 3. Resources

- [MCR - Install and Configure MATLAB Compiler Runtime](https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/dotnet/install-the-matlab-runtime.html)
- [MSVC - Linker Tools Error LNK1104](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk1104?view=msvc-170)
- [Qt Creator - Adding Libraries to Projects](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html)
- [Qt Creator - Creating Project Files (QMake)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-project-files.html)